# rosserial arduino rosmake error

Tags: ros, arduino, installation, rosserial, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm new to Arduino and ROS, and I am currently trying to install the rosserial arduino in mac. I've installed homebrew and done everything in this [page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew).

When I try installing the rosserial for Arduino IDE, I got an error for

```
rosdep install rosserial_arduino
```

the error was:

```
rosdep: error: No Valid Packages or stacks listed as arguments
```

I tried the solution [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/2554/rosserial-installation-solved?answer=4214#4214) but when I did the

```
rosmake rosserial_arduino
```

I got an error saying:

```
[rosmake] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['rosserial_arduino']
[rosmake] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names
```

And sure enough when I check the Arduino IDE I still couldn't find the ros_lib in the Examples menu.

Please help me with this problem. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12697/rosserial-arduino-rosmake-error/) by [byanana](https://answers.ros.org/users/1673/byanana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds a lot like your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable is not set correctly. Are you sure your 'rosserial_arduino' package is inside a directory that is known to ROS via ROS_PACKAGE_PATH as described [here](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables)?

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [byanana](https://answers.ros.org/users/1673/byanana/) on 2012-01-23**:
Also I seem to be able to get the rosdep command working. However I cannot install gcc-avr. anyone know why?

**Comment by [byanana](https://answers.ros.org/users/1673/byanana/) on 2012-01-23**:
Hi, I've tried setting the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH as describe in your link (export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/user/ros/ros-pkg) however when I was trying this http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment, when I get to the 2nd step (the source one) it says No such file or dir